# Properties can only be defined on Objects

Tags: reactjs, react-native, import, components, expo

I am new in react native and trying to import login component from components folder , but it is showing me error
[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMDd6.jpg)

I have tried it with this following code , What I am doing wrong

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { Text, TextInput, View, Button, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Login from './components/Login';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        display:'flex',
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
    }
});

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Login />
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

### Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={{padding: 10, justifyContent:'center'}}>
                  <TextInput
                      style={{height: 40,borderBottomWidth:2,marginBottom:20}}
                      placeholder="Enter Mobile No."
                      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
                  value=""
                  />
                  <Button title="Sign in" style={{backgroundColor:'#3b5da8'}} />
              </View>
          </View>
      );
  }
```

Comment: Hi Lokesh, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Probably not related to the error, but you're missing import of the TextInput and Button inside Login.js

Answer (score 0):

I think you got 2 issue's here.

First, your extends is not imported in `Login` component,

```
class Login extends Component
```

here you are extending `Component` but not imported from `react` package.

You can do this,

```
class Login extends React.Component
```

or you can import `Component`,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
```

Second, you cannot use `styles` defined in `App` component, inside of `Login` component directly.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
```

You need to pass `styles` as props to `Login` Component,

```
<Login styles={styles.container}/>
```

Now you can use `styles` in `Login` component using props,

```
<View style={this.props.styles}>
```

**Note:** Don't assume that, if you imported something in parent component will get applied to child component as well. For child component you need to import that separately.

For example,  In `Login` component you need to separately import `TextInput` & `Button`.

Also you don't need to import `Text, TextInput, Button, AppRegistry` in `App` component, because you are not using them. But you need to import `StyleSheet`.

**Just understand that, you only need to import whatever you use in component.**

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with the code. Make sure you import all the Components that you are using. "**Component**" module should always be imported from **React**

your App.js file should look like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { Text, TextInput, View, Button, AppRegistry, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Login from './components/Login';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        display:'flex',
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
    }
});

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Login />
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

your Login.js file should look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        display:'flex',
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
    }
});

export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={{padding: 10, justifyContent:'center'}}>
                  <TextInput
                      style={{height: 40,borderBottomWidth:2,marginBottom:20}}
                      placeholder="Enter Mobile No."
                      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
                  value=""
                  />
                  <Button title="Sign in" style={{backgroundColor:'#3b5da8'}} />
              </View>
          </View>
      );
  }

}
```